# How to make good use of stack trace (from kernel or core dump)?

Tags: c, gcc, stack-trace

If you are lucky when your kernel module crashes, you would get an oops with a log with a lot of information, such as values in the registers etc. One such information is the stack trace (The same is true for core dumps, but I had originally asked this for kernel modules). Take this example:

```
[<f97ade02>] ? skink_free_devices+0x32/0xb0 [skin_kernel]
[<f97aba45>] ? cleanup_module+0x1e5/0x550 [skin_kernel]
[<c017d0e7>] ? __stop_machine+0x57/0x70
[<c016dec0>] ? __try_stop_module+0x0/0x30
[<c016f069>] ? sys_delete_module+0x149/0x210
[<c0102f24>] ? sysenter_do_call+0x12/0x16
```

My guess is that the `+<number1>/<number2>` has something to do with the offset from function in which the error has occurred. That is, by inspecting this number, perhaps looking at the assembly output I should be able to find out the line (better yet, instruction) in which this error has occurred. Is that correct?

My question is, what are these two numbers exactly? How do you make use of them?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
skink_free_devices+0x32/0xb0
```

This means the offending instruction is `0x32` bytes from the start of the function `skink_free_devices()` which is `0xB0` bytes long in total.

If you compile your kernel with `-g` enabled, then you can get the line number inside functions where the control jumped using the tool `addr2line` or our good old `gdb`

Something like this

```
$ addr2line -e ./vmlinux 0xc01cf0d1
/mnt/linux-2.5.26/include/asm/bitops.h:244
or
$ gdb ./vmlinux
...
(gdb) l *0xc01cf0d1
0xc01cf0d1 is in read_chan (include/asm/bitops.h:244).
(...)
244     return ((1UL << (nr & 31)) & (((const volatile unsigned int *) addr)[nr >> 5])) != 0;
(...)
```

So just give the address you want to inspect to `addr2line` or `gdb` and they shall tell you the line number in the source file where the offending function is present
See [this](http://ds9a.nl/symoops.html) article for full details

**EDIT:** `vmlinux` is the uncompressed version of the kernel used for debugging and is generally found @ `/lib/modules/$(uname -r)/build/vmlinux` provided you have built your kernel from sources. `vmlinuz` that you find at `/boot` is the compressed kernel and may not be that useful in debugging

Comment: I did NOT know you can gdb the linux itself! This is awesome!

Comment: Where is `vmlinux` though? I thought that would be the linux kernel itself (in /boot) but that is `vmlinuz ...` and addr2line says "File format not recognized" Not a big deal though, as I am more interested in my own modules.

Comment: @Shahbaz vmlinuz is just the compressed and/or stripped version of `vmlinux`. BOth will generally be lying around in the `/boot` folder. I dont have my linux box with me to check up now. Google around for the two :) Here are some starters. [One](http://superuser.com/questions/62575/where-is-vmlinux-on-my-ubuntu-installation) and [Two](http://superuser.com/questions/298826/how-do-i-uncompress-vmlinuz-to-vmlinux)

Comment: @Shahbaz Check here for the `vmlinux` file  `/lib/modules/$(uname -r)/build/vmlinux` provided you've build your kernel from sources in the same machine. Else see [this](https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-users/2010-October/229714.html) post on how to get the uncompressed kernel on Ubuntu

Comment: Great! I edited my answer to add this info too so that it helps others in future

Comment: I went to the [kernel source](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/kernel/kallsyms.c) first, and then found this answer.  It is the routine `sprint_symbol()` which is producing this code.

Comment: it is working for vmlinux image but for specific module it is not working. for example "addr2line -e mymodule.ko ffffffffc01a19c4" is not giving result. can you please point out if i am doing it wrong. Thanks!

Comment: @raj_gt1, you probably need to build your module with debug symbols as well.

Answer (score 1):

For Emacs users, [here](https://github.com/mgalgs/kernel-stack-trace-mode)'s is a major mode to easily jump around within the stack trace (uses `addr2line` internally).

Disclaimer: I wrote it :)

Comment: There is something for vim (sorry for necro): https://github.com/rzwisler/oops_trace.vim/blob/master/plugin/oops_trace.vim

Answer (score 0):

regurgitating [this answer](https://serverfault.com/a/901534/500287) you need to use `faddr2line`

In my case I had the following truncated call trace:

```
[  246.790938][   T35] Call trace:
[  246.794075][   T35]  __switch_to+0x10c/0x180
[  246.798348][   T35]  __schedule+0x278/0x6e0
[  246.802531][   T35]  schedule+0x44/0xd0
[  246.806368][   T35]  rpm_resume+0xf4/0x628
[  246.810463][   T35]  __pm_runtime_resume+0x94/0xc0
[  246.815257][   T35]  macb_open+0x30/0x2b8
[  246.819265][   T35]  __dev_open+0x10c/0x188
```

and ran the following in the [mainline linux kernel](https://github.com/torvalds/linux.git):

```sh
./scripts/faddr2line vmlinux macb_open+0x30/0x2b8
```

giving the output

```
macb_open+0x30/0x2b8:
pm_runtime_get_sync at include/linux/pm_runtime.h:386
(inlined by) macb_open at drivers/net/ethernet/cadence/macb_main.c:2726
```