# Character device driver hangs the system - how to avoid?

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I'm writing a simple writable character device driver (2.6.32-358.el6.x86_64, under VirtualBox), and since it's not mature yet, it tends to crash/freeze (segfaults, infinite loops).

I'm testing it like this: `$> echo "some data" > /dev/my_dev`, and if crash/freeze occurs, the whole system (VirtualBox) freezes. I tried to move all the work to another kernel thread to avoid the system-wide freeze, but it doesn't help.

Is it possible to "isolate" such a crash/freeze, so that I'd be able to kill the process, in whose context the kernel module runs?

Answer (score 3):

The module runs in kernel context. That's why debugging it is difficult and bugs can easily crash the system. Infinite loop is not really an issue as it just slows the system down, but doesn't cause a crash. Writing to the wrong memory region however is fatal.

If you are lucky, you would get a kernel oops before the freeze. If you test your code in one of the TTYs, rather than the GUI, then you might immediately see the oops (kernel BUG log) on the screen which you can study and [might be helpful to you](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10171984/912144).

In my experience however, it's best to write and test the kernel-independent code in user-space, probably with mock functions and test it heavily, run `valgrind` on it, and make sure it doesn't have bugs. Then use it in kernel space. You'd be surprised at how much of a kernel module's code may in fact not need kernel context at all. Of course this very much depends on the functionality of the kernel module.

To actually debug the code in kernel space, there are tools which I have never used, such as kgdb. What I do myself usually is a mixture of `printk`s and binary search. That is, if the crash is so severe that the kernel oops is not shown at all. First, I put `printk` (possibly with a delay after) in different places to see which parts of the code are reached before the oops. `tail -f /var/log/messages` comes in handy. Then, I do binary search; disable half of the code to see if the crash occurs. If not, *possibly* the problem is in the second half. If it occurs, surely the problem is in the first half. Repeat!

The ultimate way of writing a bug-free kernel module is to write code that doesn't have bugs in the first place. Of course, this is rarely possible, but if you write clean and undefined-behavior-free C code and write very concise functions whose correctness is obvious and you pay attention to the boundaries of arrays, it's not that hard.

Comment: Well, binary search with `printk` is what I'm doing. The problem is that every "miss" requires VB restart. To get "oops", I actually have to rebuild kernel with `CONFIG_DEBUG_INFO`, right?

Comment: @IgorR. I'm not sure. The default always worked for me. You can take a look at where the `BUG` macro is defined to check for yourself.