# 'scheduling while atomic' error when USB keyboard is removed, and how to read the error message?

Tags: linux, multithreading, linux-kernel, scheduled-tasks

I'm using USB keyboard to make virtual console on the LCD and it works well, but when I plug out the USB keyboard, it gives me the message on the console.

```
# usb 1-1: USB disconnect, device number 2
BUG: scheduling while atomic: khubd/12/0x00000002
Modules linked in:
[c03b58dc : wait_for_common+0xcc/0x1a0 ]
[c027fc2c : devtmpfs_delete_node+0xa0/0xc8 ]
[c027920c : device_del+0x160/0x188 ]
[c02d7a3c : evdev_disconnect+0xc/0x30 ]
[c02d5960 : input_unregister_device+0xcc/0x174 ]
[c02f6fb8 : hidinput_disconnect+0x4c/0x70 ]
[c02f33c4 : hid_disconnect+0x48/0x58 ]
[c02f343c : hid_device_remove+0x68/0x80 ]
[c027ba90 : __device_release_driver+0x5c/0xb8 ]
[c027bb00 : device_release_driver+0x14/0x24 ]
[c027b628 : bus_remove_device+0xe8/0x10c ]
[c02791b4 : device_del+0x108/0x188 ]
[c02f327c : hid_destroy_device+0x20/0x3c ]
[c02fb770 : usbhid_disconnect+0x18/0x34 ]
[c02bea74 : usb_unbind_interface+0xd4/0x148 ]
[c027ba90 : __device_release_driver+0x5c/0xb8 ]
```

I know this 'scheduling while atomic' is printed when the kernel tried to sleep in atomic context. (like during interrupt). From the message I can see it started all from __device_release_driver function and eventually ended up with wait_for_common function which is like sleeping using scheduling. Somewhere I read this is a kernel bug and I should upgrade my kernel(which is not a choice for me). I'm not sure if this is really a kernel bug. (I'm using linux 3.3)
My question is, in the above function call list, what's the numbers following + at each function name? (for example in [c03b58dc : wait_for_common+0xcc/0x1a0 ], the 0xcc/0x1a0 part.)
Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to make good use of stack trace (from kernel or core dump)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10171984/how-to-make-good-use-of-stack-trace-from-kernel-or-core-dump)

Comment: The kernel traces are of the form `label+offset/limit`.  If you have symbols present, then *label* is a function name.  The *offset* is the particular instruction that caused the *sub-function* call.  If the *offset* is greater than the *limit*, it indicates that some *unknown/unmarked* function made the call.  Look at `objdump -S vmlinux` output to see what function it maybe.

Comment: It is absolutely, definitely a kernel bug.

Comment: In my case, it was caused by my mistake. See the answer below..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was because an 'else' keyword prevented spin_unlock_irqrestore from being called in the urb_dequeue function that I was using. After removing the 'else' everything is ok. Just for your information.